# Finish uploading files and then execute the jsf:action of the button

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces, upload

The fileupload, as seen in the code, call a method, which saves files in a List <>. The upload files from the button with the ruling PF ('fileupload') upload ().; 
What I need here is that when you upload the "n" preloaded, recently at the end of the upload, execute the action method of the button.

```
<p:fileUpload id="fileupload"
              widgetVar="fileupload"
              fileUploadListener="#{incidentBean.handleAttachment}"
              mode="advanced"
              label="Adjuntar (máx. 800kb)"
              invalidFileMessage="Archivo inválido"
              update="form-attachments"
              allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$/"
              multiple="true"
              sizeLimit="820000"
              invalidSizeMessage="Archivo pesado" />

<button class="btn btn-info"
        type="submit"
        jsf:id="cmd"
        jsf:action="#{incidentBean.save()}"
        jsf:onclick="PF('fileupload').fileupload();">
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply connect the `oncomplete` attribute of the fileupload to a `<p:remoteCommand/>`, such that you'll have:

```
  <p:remoteCommand name="save" actionListener="#{incidentBean.save}"/>
```

and

```
  <p:fileUpload id="fileupload" oncomplete="save();"  widgetVar="fileupload"/>
```

Comment: The oncomplete callback executes after a fileupload request. In the case of multiple upload, 2 requests are made and oncomplete will execute two times. You'd have to change oncomplete="save();" for oncomplete="if(this.files.length == 0) save()"